# How to use Pandoc image alignment to align two images in the same row?

Tags: image, alignment, pandoc

From the pandoc documentation I know how to insert an image

http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#images

Now I want to align two images in the same row, how can I do that?
My desired output format is pdf.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
![](tests/lalune.jpg)\ ![](tests/lalune.jpg)
```

This will give you two side-by-side images.  You won't have a caption, though; pandoc only treats an image as a captioned figure if it is by itself in a paragraph.

Comment: Thanks, it works. But I have another problem now. My images are a little large, and when put in the same row they cannot fit into one slide. Is it possible to control the size of the image?

Comment: You can't specify the size in Markdown. You have to modify your image externally

Comment: I feel like http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/139205/13192 should be able to be combined with http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/01/14/how-to-display-side-by-side-figurs-in-latex/ or similar to allow raw latex commands with `\subfigure`, but when I tried it, I got an error (but I've since merged the figures, and I didn't copy down the error, sorry).

Comment: The figure size issue has been addressed in more recent versions of pandoc. You can now use ![](tests/lalune.jpg){height=3cm} This should give your images all the same height.

Answer (score 15):

Expanding on from John's answer, if you do want a single caption under two side by side figures, a 'hack' would be to do this:

```
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png){width=60%}
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png){width=40%}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\caption{A single caption for the two subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

This results in one caption for two images placed side by side. You might need to tweak each individual image's width setting, or the [`!h` caption placement specifier](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Floats,_Figures_and_Captions) to get things looking like this:

[image: hacked caption]

I found this helpful because you don't have to download the picture off the internet as in a pure LaTeX `\subfigure` solution. I.e. just use pandoc markdown to get the image, and LaTeX to generate the caption.

If you want to go crazy, you can actually use the same idea above to make subfigure captions like so:

```
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png){width=60%}
![](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png){width=40%}
\begin{figure}[!h]
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
\caption{Caption for the left subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.4\textwidth}
\caption{Caption for the right subfigure}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{A single caption for the two subfigures}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Edit 20180910:

You'll need to include the following packages in the pandoc YAML frontmatter/header:

```
header-includes: |
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{subcaption}
```

Comment: I am getting a "! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined." error if I include the code as you suggested.

Comment: Oops, forgot to mention that you'll need to include the packages. In pandoc you would have ```header-includes: |
        \usepackage{caption}
        \usepackage{subcaption}``` I'll edit the answer to be clearer.

Comment: I had a conflict, and had to remove subfigures package, to use the subcaption package. It works now though.

Comment: Sometimes the caption (Figure 1. ...) goes into next page. I am trying to fix this by wrapping around a minipage or vbox but I am not capable of doing so. It is the first time I try to use such environments in Pandoc and I dont know if its even possible. My current error message is `l.500 ...backslash begin\{minipage\}\{\linewidth\}`. I am sure someone thought of this. Any ideas?

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but how did you center those?

Comment: Well, finally I decided to go full latex just for figures. And for the case where I don't want floating figures, I use [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226313/how-can-i-insert-multiple-images-with-captions-in-a-non-floating-environment) approach using `captionof`

Answer (score 0):

One simple way is convert your file first to a .tex file, where you can adjust your image alignment with LaTeX command [minipage](http://www.sascha-frank.com/latex-minipage.html) or so. Then you could obtain your .pdf file running **latex** or **pandoc** in command line. See [Pandoc Demos](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/demos.html) for example.

Comment: I am looking for a way to directly go from markdown to pdf, otherwise I will write latex directly.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a preprocessor like gpp to include options like align image. Or you could do it like how John told you:

```
![](tests/lalune.jpg)\ ![](tests/lalune.jpg)
```

Comment: This is a duplicate of [John's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15755523/3817004).